# View binding of a frgament inside a constraint layout not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I have the following code:

activity_reminders.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".locationreminders.RemindersActivity">

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ReminderActivity.kt

```
class RemindersActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityRemindersBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityRemindersBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            (binding.navHostFragment as NavHostFragment).navController.popBackStack()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

}

binding.navHostFragment in unresolved and i don't understand why, if i change the type of view in anything differnt then "fragment" the view binding works.
Is possible to use view vbinding for a fragment inside another view?

Comment: did you enable view binding in Gradle?

Comment: What error is displayed in logcat?

Comment: Yes, I've enabled buildFeatures { viewBinding true } and the build error is: "Unresolved reference: navHostFragment"

Answer (score 0):

I found the following as a workaround solution to get the fragment.

```
val navHostFragment = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
navHostFragment.popBackStack()
```

I think that is not possible to use view binding with a <fragment> because fragment is not a descendent of View.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
(binding.navHostFragment as NavHostFragment).navController.popBackStack()
```

Use the following code:

```
(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment).navController.popBackStack()
```